# Can I Change The 240V Coming Into the Main Panel To 2 120V Panels?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, 240v, inverter

I have a generator that has a 240V plug which connects to the main house panel via 8/3 Romex (Black, Red, White, Ground). The generator has two 30A breakers on it. Can I split that wire coming into the house to (2) 30 amp 120V panels?

I don't have any 240V in the house and wanted 120V to go into an inverter to charge batteries and the other 120V to run separate things that wouldn't be on the main panel like an electric water heater. Is this possible?

Comment: Where are you located in the world?

Comment: Theoretically you can do that, but ... lets wait for our CODE experts

Comment: Wait, do you have any utility connection at all?  Or are you solely on generator/solar/etc.?

Comment: In the US, no utility connection. Just a generator and inverter/batteries.

Comment: Wait. I'm confused. Do you feed this panel from a generator? Or do you feed it from inverter/batteries? You're just blowing past a bunch of important stuff about how they interact.  Is this stuff you haven't figured out yet?  If so, [edit] and clarify more about what you're trying to do. That why you're not getting into an XY problem.

Comment: look into connecting the coolant loop of your generator to your hot water (using a heat exchanger) , using electric here is a waste of money.

Answer (score 4):

No need. With most breaker panels, you have *alternating rows* for the two legs. Using a typical odd-on-the-left and even-on-the-right starting at the top, that means:

- 1,2,5,6,9,10,13,14,17,18, etc. on one hot.
- 3,4,7,8,11,12,15,16,19,20, etc. on the other hot.

So you can use a totally standard panel and if you don't actually use any double-breakers, everything will be 120V. If you later decide to use 240V, upsize the generator, etc. you are all set. Even if you can't see *ever* needing 240V, one big panel takes less space and costs less than two smaller panels.